# Why flutter auto import does not work in VsCode

Tags: flutter, auto-import

Recently the auto import feature for packages and widgets stopped from working, How can I solve it and back it to work? Here an example for import the material flutter package.. in the past when I used to click on fast solve button it was give me an option to import it automatically .[Flutter auto import does not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXr3K.png)

Comment: Did you try: `flutter pub get` and then restarting your window?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/67092300/15166812

Comment: Thanks @Nitesh putting the dependencies under __dependencies:__ solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

import material.dart to get the rest of the widget working.

Comment: My problem isn't here, I know that but the auto import in general does not work

Answer (score 0):

I've had to deal with that for a month or so, and I only managed to solve it a few days ago.
If your problem is anything like mine then it's probably due to one of your settings.

The brute force solution I found is to completely clear your settings.json file and set your preferences again one by one.
Only add those you actually need. I had a lot of them which didn't change much or anything I could notice.

You could also comment out each line one by one to try to find out what exact setting is causing the issue but that's more tedious than doing it all over again.